# Need Help! Code that works in one javascript function doesn't work in another yet both seem to be formatted properly

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The function sumValues1 is called on blur from text boxes txtShare1, txtHST1, txtPST1, txtCardFee1 and txtOther1.  The result is that the sum of the values of these text boxes are placed in the value of textbox txtTotal1.  This function works perfectly.

I then added a txtGrossSales and a txtBalance textbox.  The function getBalance is used onblur for the GrossSales textbox.The first step was to place the value of txtGrossSales into the txtBalance textbox.  If I do only that it works. However when I add a section to getValues() that subtracts the value of txtTotal1.  This should happen each time I onblur from the other textboxes, i.e.txtShare1, txtHST1, txtPST1, txtCardFee1 and txtOther1, however it doesn't work when I perform the very first subtraction of txtGrossSales.value minus txtTotal1.value in getBalance() as it is shown below.

Anything will help.  THank you in advance for your consideration and assistance.

The problem is when I ask it

enter code here

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="breakdown4.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="TestJavascript.breakdown4" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
      <script>
          function sumValues1() {
              var textVal1 = document.getElementById('txtShare1');
              var textVal2 = document.getElementById('txtHST1');
              var textVal3 = document.getElementById('txtPST1');
              var textVal4 = document.getElementById('txtCardFee1');
              var textVal5 = document.getElementById('txtOther1');
              var textVal6 = document.getElementById('txtTotal1');


              textVal1 = textVal1.value == null ? 0 : Number(textVal1.value);
              textVal2 = textVal2.value == null ? 0 : Number(textVal2.value);
              textVal3 = textVal3.value == null ? 0 : Number(textVal3.value);
              textVal4 = textVal4.value == null ? 0 : Number(textVal4.value);
              textVal5 = textVal5.value == null ? 0 : Number(textVal5.value);


              textVal6.value = textVal1 + textVal2 + textVal3 + textVal4 + textVal5;



              //alert(txtBalance.value);




          };
        function getBalance() {
            var txtGrossSales = document.getElementById('txtGrossSales');
            var txtBalance = document.getElementById('txtBalance');
            var textVal6 = document.getElementById('txtTotal1');
            //var txtTotal1 = documnent.getElementById('txtTotal1');
            txtVal6 = txtVal6.value == null ? 0 : Number(txtVal6.value);
            txtGrossSales = txtGrossSales.value == null ? 0 : Number(txtGrossSales.value);

            //txtBalance = txtBalance.value == null ? 0 : Number(txtBalance.value);
            txtBalance.value = txtGrossSales-txtVal6.value;
            //alert(txtBalance);
        }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table>
         <tr>
                        <td class="alignright"><asp:Label Font-Bold="true" ID="Label23" runat="server" Text="Gross Sales"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td colspan="6" class="alignleft">
                           <%-- <asp:TextBox ID="txtGrossSales" onfocus = "this.select();" TabIndex="1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode!=13);"  OnTextChanged="Values1_Changed" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtGrossSales" onfocus = "this.select();" TabIndex="1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" onblur ="getBalance()"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><asp:Label Font-Bold="true" ID="Label24" runat="server" Text="Share"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td><asp:Label Font-Bold="true" ID="Label25" runat="server" Text="HST"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td><asp:Label Font-Bold="true" ID="Label26" runat="server" Text="PST"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td><asp:Label Font-Bold="true" ID="Label27" runat="server" Text="Card Fee"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td><asp:Label Font-Bold="true" ID="Label28" runat="server" Text="Other"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td><asp:Label Font-Bold="true" ID="Label29" runat="server" Text="Total"></asp:Label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:Label Font-Bold="true" ID="Label30" runat="server" Text="MIM"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtShare1" runat="server" TabIndex="2" onfocus = "this.select();" Font-Bold="true" onblur="sumValues1()"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtHST1" runat="server" TabIndex="3" onfocus = "this.select();" Font-Bold="true" onblur="sumValues1()"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPST1" runat="server" TabIndex="4" onfocus = "this.select();"  Font-Bold="true" onblur="sumValues1()"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtCardFee1" runat="server" TabIndex="5" onfocus = "this.select();"  Font-Bold="true" onblur="sumValues1()"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtOther1" runat="server" TabIndex="6" onfocus = "this.select();" onblur="sumValues1()"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtTotal1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtType1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Visible="False" Text="1"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="alignright"><asp:Label Font-Bold="true" ID="Label34" runat="server" Text="Balance"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td colspan="6" class="alignleft"><asp:TextBox ID="txtBalance" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
    </table>    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does your browser have a developer console? If so, open it. Then locate the error and the line number.

Comment: input value is not going to be null

Comment: There was a type in my code that I found when looking at the developer console.

Comment: There was a typo in my code that I found when looking at the developer console. However, now when I call the getBalance() function I get NaN in the txtBalance textbox.

Comment: The reason the txtBalance receives the NaN value is that the txtTotal1 value is undefined yet I preset the value to 0 and when I place values in the fields that total to  txtTotal1 in the sumValues funtion it all seems to work.